# Sorting nested collection in projection: Unable to cast object of type 'SortOp' to type 'ProjectOp'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using projection of query results to a custom type, which isn't a part of entity data model:

```
public sealed class AlgoVersionCacheItem : NotificationObject
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderTitle { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public int CachedVersion { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> AvailableVersions { get; set; }
}
```

I want `AvailableVersions` to be sorted in descending order. Hence, I've tried to add sorting for `AvailableVersions` in projection:

```
        return someQueryable
            .Select(version => new AlgoVersionCacheItem
            {
                OrderId = version.OrderId,
                OrderTitle = version.Order.Title,
                CurrentVersion = version.Order.CurrentAlgoVersionId,
                CachedVersion = version.Id,
                AvailableVersions = version
                    .Order
                    .AlgoVersions
                    .Where(v => (allowUncommittedVersions || v.Statuses.Any(s => s.AlgoVersionStatusListItemId == ModelConstants.AlgoVersionCommitted_StatusId)) && v.Id != version.Id)
                    .OrderByDescending(v => v.Id) // this line will cause exception
                    .Select(v => v.Id)
            })
            .Where(item => item.AvailableVersions.Any())
            .OrderByDescending(item => item.OrderId)
            .ToArray();
```

With sorting, execution of the query throws an `System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException` with `System.InvalidCastException` as inner exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SortOp' to type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp'

Without `.OrderByDescending(v => v.Id)` everything works fine.
Is this yet another feature, that isn't supported in Entity Framework, or I've missed something?

P.S. I know, that I can sort items later at client side, but I'm wondering about sorting at the server side.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you switch the select and orderby around - i.e. .Select(v => v.Id).OrderByDescending(v => v)

Comment: @MattWhetton: yes, the same error.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the query pipeline. I opened a work item for this on the EF codeplex site: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1750

Comment: @Dennis - I am having hard time reproducing this issue. Can you post the stack trace and how the entity you refer to as `version` is defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in EF. I was able to repro this on both EF5 and EF6. I think you should be able to workaround the bug by filtering records before creating the results i.e.:

```
return someQueryable
    .Where(version => version.Order.AlgoVersions.Any(v => (allowUncommittedVersions || v.Statuses.Any(s => s.AlgoVersionStatusListItemId == ModelConstants.AlgoVersionCommitted_StatusId)) && v.Id != version.Id))
    .Select(version => new AlgoVersionCacheItem
        {
            OrderId = version.OrderId,
            OrderTitle = version.Order.Title,
                CurrentVersion = version.Order.CurrentAlgoVersionId,
                CachedVersion = version.Id,
                AvailableVersions = version
                    .Order
                    .AlgoVersions
                    .Where(v => (allowUncommittedVersions || v.Statuses.Any(s => s.AlgoVersionStatusListItemId == ModelConstants.AlgoVersionCommitted_StatusId)) && v.Id != version.Id)
                    .OrderByDescending(v => v.Id) // this line will cause exception
                    .Select(v => v.Id)
        })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.OrderId)
    .ToArray();
```

I also have a feeling that this query could be simplified if you go from the other side of relationship (i.e. from Orders) but it may depend on how the `someQueryable` is created.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Linq query was selecting a new anonymous construct with one property being set to a collection `ToList()` extension method. I removed the embedded execution, the error went away, and the system still worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As others have described, this is a bug in EF, but there are several ways to fix it.

If you check the query in the original post, it has a `.Any()` on a nested collection which occurs after a projection which has a sort on it, the key parts being:

```
return someQueryable
    .Select(version => new
    {
        AvailableVersions = version
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Id)
            .Select(v => v.Id)
    })
    .Where(item => item.AvailableVersions.Any())
    .ToArray();
```

If you modify that above code to add a predicate to the `Any()` function, it will avoid the bug. For example, the following will work:

```
return someQueryable
    .Select(version => new
    {
        AvailableVersions = version
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Id)
            .Select(v => v.Id)
    })
    .Where(item => item.AvailableVersions.Any(v => true))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: What is `someQueryable`? It would be more clear if you'd tell how `version` is a collection type.

Comment: @GertArnold please check the original post. This answer uses the same variable names as the OP asked for in their question. It's a trimmed down version of their code with only the relevant portions to demonstrate the bug.

Comment: But then `version.OrderByDescending` is not correct. For the rest I think adding `v => true` is a useful work-around.